# Magento Theming Between Community & Enterprise

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, theming

I have recently been developing a theme for Magento Community v.1.7, and have found out that my client needs to launch on Enterprise.

My current theme is built on top of the Base Community theme.

If I use this theme in a Enterprise install, will it work properly? Is the Base theme for Enterprise the same as in Community?

I know this question has been asked before, but I saw this article (http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magentos-theme-hierarchy#3.2) that talks about the theme hierarchy being changed around. I'm hoping that this makes it so themes built on top of Base will transfer over easily.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to build a theme is creating it with your own package name and inside it a default theme. But as you say you have already built it on top of your Base theme, which though not a good practice, will work fine in Enterprise version.